# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This error seems to occur a lot according to all the posts I've found on the web and especially here on stackoverflow. I understand that you need to install the gems **execjs** and **rubyracer**, restart your server and try again and the error should be resolved.

Now it's worth mentioning that I'm only starting out learning rails so I don't really understand all the concepts yet. Infact this is the first time I'm trying to run my own 'Hello World' rails app..

My system details are:

- Windows 8 64-bit
- ruby 1.9.3
- rails 3.2.11

also this is my gem list:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS::RuntimeError on windows 7 trying to follow rubytutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-7-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are telling its your first try, i guess node.js is missing in your system.

I suggest you to install it first [http://nodejs.org/download/][1]

[1]: http://nodejs.org/download/ and try.

You could see in application.js

> > //= require_tree .

This line expecting node.js.

Your application will run by removing this line but its not recommended

Comment: I downloaded and installed node.js with the windows installer. Is it necessary to restart my system? Are there anything else I need to do after the installer finished?

Comment: Yes please restart your system and try

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much, now I can go on learning and maybe stop making n00b mistakes.