# ExecJS::RuntimeError [Rails 4] Node.js already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, execjs

I have an ExecJS::RuntimeError on my Rails 4 app. I'm on Windows 7 64bit. I have already checked these two answers :

[ExecJS::RuntimeError in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394528/execjsruntimeerror-in-rails-3)

and [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Then, I tried :

Install node.js, restard my computer, but still doesn't work !!

OR

Modify C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\execjs-2.0.2\lib\execjs\runtimes.rb by changing.

```
 JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
          :name        => "JScript",
          :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
          :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
          :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
        )
```

by

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
      :name        => "JScript",
      :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
      :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
      :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
    )
```

But it does not work neither !

I know that remove the line `//= require_tree .` of `application.js` works but I don't want a bad fix.

What should I do ?

I precise that ALL my js files (except application.js) are empty.

My gemfile :

```
 ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  #advanced stuff
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.4.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'execjs'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I "resolved" the problem, I formated my laptop and installed Windows 7 Ultimate...

Answer (score 1):

Based on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial I think you should try to see which .js file generates the error.

> That line is compiling every .js.coffee file in app/assets/javascripts
>   into JavaScript and then adding it to your layout (but only in
>   development mode; in production mode, the compiled js is added to your
>   application.js file). Having require_tree . shouldn't be causing
>   errors, **so somehow you've got an issue with one of the files that's
>   being included**. Can you post a list of all the files in your
>   app/assets/javascripts directory? Also, you can try completely
>   deleting the contents of sessions.js.coffee and adding back //=
>   require_tree . and see if the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:-

```
   add gem therubyracer to your gemfile and then do bundle install
```

Comment: open windows command prompt `cmd` and type `node`, are you able to run nodejs terminal?

Comment: I've added my gemfile, yeah I can run nodejs terminal

Comment: your gemfile does not contains the therubyracer gem, please add it and then do bundle, and try running the server again

Comment: hey, does your gemfile contains `therubyracer` gem, if not add it.

Comment: The rubyracer is already installed on my computer, when I type `gem list`, it is in the list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46735/discussion-between-sachin-singh-and-duques-l)

Answer (score 0):

Window already has ExecRuntime engine installed and it does not need anything to done. It should automatically pickup best runtime available. You does not even need to install nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I would not spend the effort trying to patch for Windows. I recommend installing 'therubyracer' gem [V8 embedded] or node.js. If the issue persists; please provide a copy of your Gemfile.lock so we can verify your bundle install.

Comment: I already installed therubyracer gem by using https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows

Answer (score 0):

Change the ExecJS version to 1.2.4

1. Go to the Gemfile
2. Type gem 'execjs', '1.2.4'
3. Go to the command line in the application: bundle install
4. Prosper

Answer (score 0):

Please never develop Rails project in special folder such as Google Drive Syns. This might help you. The full detail is here: http://www.angkorbrick.com/rails-should-not-put-project-repository-in-google-drive-syns-folder/