# Error when Installing ruby on rails on Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I need to install ruby on rails for college. I can get as far as the 'welcome page' but when I try to run a sample page I'm getting an error.

A friend of mine has a similar problem and he too uses windows 8.

I got out an old laptop ( Windows 7 ) and installed it and I'm not getting the error page so I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with Windows 8.

Screenshot here...

http://i48.tinypic.com/29c5ms1.png

Comment: I'd recommend posting text, not images.

Comment: Can you include the error message you're getting in the question please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS::RuntimeError on windows 7 trying to follow rubytutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-7-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either install nodejs, or add TheRubyRacer gem to your project. To do the latter, edit your Gemfile and add:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

And that should fix it.

Comment: Actually, `therubyracer` gem depends on `libv8` which doesn't compile on Windows.

Comment: I seen in a similar thread that by removing '//= require_tree' it works but I'm not sure if this will affect other things.

Comment: yes, installing nodejs seems to have solved the problem. thanks Alfonso.