# RoR + Gem execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/run times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

At windows platform I am trying to run one of my application but at console it is giving some strange issue.

> Issue :
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/run
>   times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime.
>   Seehttps://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available
>   runtimes.

I have not added execjs gem in my Gemfile but even though it is showing the name of gem in list. Even though I tried my uninstalling it but again while running bundle install , it again appears. Just because of that, I am unable to run the console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or any other of the [listed javascript runtimes](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast after a lot of Googling, I found that due to some dependencies execjs get installed. While bundle install, due to sprockets dependencies execjs get loaded in the machine.

> Step 1 : Delete the folder 'execjs-1.4.0' from 
>   C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems
>
> Step 2 : Remove dependency ( sprockets gem ) from the system by using gem uninstall.
>
> Step 3 : Delete the Gemfile.lock and Run Bundle Install

In this way, issue is resolved at my machine. Thanks a lot Thomas for your valuable suggestion.

**UPDATE : 26 March 2013**

Refer this link for the installation of NODE.JS -> [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-7-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Then run *bundle install*