# What can I do if I can't use //= require_tree .?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still getting the `ExecJS::RuntimeError` even when I went through the ways to fix it based on this post: [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-7-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

I found out that my issue was when I require the `tree .` in my file. This error came up when i simply generated a new controller called `info` and it made the coffee script for it.

Putting `*= require info` doesn't work either as it still throws the same error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /

["ok","(function() {\n\n\n}).call(this);\n"] 
(in C:/Users/..../assets/javascripts/info.js.coffee)
```

So what else could I use besides `//= require_tree .`?

P.S.Im on Windows 7 64x.

Comment: If you remove all contents of `assets/javascripts/info.js.coffee`, do you still get the error?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Yeah I still get it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't use `//= require_tree .` Instead I put `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name %>`  in `app/views/layouts/application` so it will include the javascript file that belongs to the controller. 
If that doesn't work out, you may want to change the JS runtime to `node.js`

Hope this helps

Comment: When I run the `thin` server I see it says `The system cannot find the path specified.`. When I run `node -v` it shows me the version and my PATH is all setup, yet node doesn't working. How would I change the JS runtime to node?

Comment: I suppose you just comment out the `execjs` in the gem file, and install the node.js in whatever way it is installed on windows