# Rails - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have installed Rails and Ruby on Windows with railsinstaller. The problem is, when I run the rails command, it gives me: "The system cannot find the path specified."

I am running windows 7 x64 and Ruby 2.20.

I tried uninstalling Rails and installing it again; that does not help. Ruby commands execute, like `ruby -v`, but `rails -v=` dont work.

Comment: what is your requirement ? Do you want to install ruby on rails on your windows machine ?

Comment: well yes. i did install it. i want to be able to run it

Comment: This problem gave me the opportunity to say "You had one job, railsinstaller.org" :). Fortunately this question and its answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Go into C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0. In some of the .bat files, you'll find the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "C:/Users/emachnic/GitRepos/railsinstaller-windows/stage/Ruby2.2.0/bin/tilt" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Delete that and paste in the text below:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

Comment: This is how a proper answer should be. :) Saved my time. :)

Comment: @scripter "In some of the .bat files," In which batch files we have to make these changes. Do we have to make these changes in all of the batch files because all of my batch files contains the upper code.

Comment: It's better to do. There are only few batch files. However making changes on rails.bat will work also.

Comment: @scripter is right, it's the specified files.  Took me 5 minutes to go through and paste the code in each, it's not too painful.

Comment: This is still the case on RailsInstaller for Ruby 2.3.0. Commonly, you just need to change the `bin\rails.bat` and `bin\bundle.bat`.

Comment: I've had the same problem and I solved it changing the content of the file `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin\rails.exe` for the one in this answer. Sadly RailsInstaller come with a couple of bugs, it would be nice to install Rails over Windows without doing stuff like this.

Comment: found this to correct a straight install on Windows, pretty careless that the install doesn't work

Comment: Works. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 43):

This is due to a bug in RailsInstaller, where two files have the location of `ruby.exe` hard-coded to work only on the RailsInstaller dev's machine. In `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\rails.bat` (this is the default install folder, you might have `rails.bat` somewhere else if you picked a different install folder) you'll find these two lines:

```
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "C:/Users/emachnic/GitRepos/railsinstaller-windows/stage/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

The emachnic user is the RailsInstaller developer. As a workaround, you can change these folders to the ones on your computer. For the default install folder, you'd change these to:

```
@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

You will have to repeat this change for two similar lines in `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\bundle.bat` as well.

Run `rails -v` to verify that rails is now working.

You can follow this issue on their git repo here: https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/issues/70

Comment: Thanks it saved a lot of my time

Comment: I'm 2 hours deep following a convoluted tutorial to get Redmine installed in Xampp. Not my nicest experience with a new language. `rails -v` is alive and kicking.  I'm still alive...  Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Win 10 as well

Answer (score 20):

The solution is specified on github issues of railsinstaller - https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/issues/73

Comment: Yes, it looks like it was a build problem for the Rails Installer leading to broken paths to ruby.exe. You probably don't need to fix them all but affected BAT files are: bundle.bat, bundler.bat, erubis.bat, nokogiri.bat, rails.bat, sprockets.bat, swlite3_ruby.bat, tilt.bat

Answer (score 9):

I opened all the `.bat` files under **C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin** in **Sublime Text**, and replaced with `Ctrl+Shift+F`,

this
`@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe"`
with this
`@"%~dp0ruby.exe"`
across all files that had a match.

Took only a couple of seconds. This might help someone who stumbles across it after me and is daunted by the idea of performing a find and replace over multiple files.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem on my windows machine by doing

1. gem install bundler
2. bundler install
3. Number 1 and 2 fixed the problem and installed all gems.

Comment: This re-generate all gems with the correct path to ruby.exe.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a super easy way to do @JayantBhawal's solution (worked perfectly fine for me) with [Windows Powershell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx), which you should all have since this seems like a problem exclusive to Windows machines. It looks complicated but really all it's doing is replacing all the instances of `C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe` with `%~dp0ruby.exe` in the .bat files. Just open up Powershell, cd to `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin`, and copy this small script:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.bat | Foreach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.name ) | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ -replace "C:\\Users\\emachnic\\GitRepos\\railsinstaller-windows\\stage\\Ruby2.2.0\\bin\\ruby.exe", "%~dp0ruby.exe" 
} | Set-Content $_.name}
```

After you hit enter, you should find that all the instances of that string have been replaced. GL

edit: updated version 2.2.0 -> 2.3.0

Comment: this is a great solution ! 

Press Win + R then type "powershell" hit enter.

Above code works great but current version of Ruby s 2.3.0 as I'm writing this. so proper script would be 

Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.bat | Foreach-Object {
(Get-Content $_.name ) | ForEach-Object { 
    $_ -replace "C:\\Users\\emachnic\\GitRepos\\railsinstaller-windows\\stage\\Ruby2.3.0\\bin\\ruby.exe", "%~dp0ruby.exe" 
} | Set-Content $_.name}

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue a couple of days ago. It seems like all of a sudden after you run Rails many times on Windows, playing with the cmd command prompt, changing the command background and text colors or opening more than one command prompt window at the same time, and then you try to run the command 'rails server' 'rails new App' or 'bundle install' you get the message  "The system cannot find the path specified"

I solved that problem by running the command:
'gem install _____' (fill out that line with: 'bundle', 'bundler' and 'byebug'), which are the names of three .bat files (run that command with each .bat file name ONE AT A TIME). Once you have done that, test it! Try to create a new app, bundle install and rails server. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and running `gem install rails` in the command prompt it works.

Regards,
T.S.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while researching the same problem earlier, and I just fixed it for myself (Windows 8.1) so I thought I would answer it. I was trying to run Ruby 2.2 on Windows 8.1 using RailsInstaller. I am now able to run Ruby and Rails, albeit an older version. I think this is a problem with 64-bit architecture versus 32-bit, the latter of which seems to run fine. Here's how I did it:

1. First, read [this blog post](http://carol-nichols.com/2011/03/17/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/) and see if this solves your problem, though I don't think it will. I used `regedit.exe` to find the AutoRun instance in question. I didn't have one, so I tried the next step.
2. Uninstall the Ruby 2.2 version of RailsInstaller (go into your `control panel` > `programs and features` then uninstall `RailsInstaller`.
3. Then, install the 1.9.3 version. Go [here](http://railsinstaller.org/en) and CTRL+F "1.9" to find the Ruby 1.9.3 version of RailsInstaller.
4. Once installed, make sure to run a `gem update --system` to update all of your gems. I had trouble running `rails new` until I did the gem update. Now everything works fine.

So, you'll be using a slightly older version of Ruby but everything should be working okay. This solution worked for me and I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but i already fixed it. The problem was in a path specified in rails.bat or something like that. I believe it is temporary until the author of railsinstaller fixes it. It was in issues on github.

Comment: @Severus do you have a link

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards, Yes - https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/issues/73  Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix for the above problem is very simple.

The problem is happening because in the installation directory the batch that you have is taking default path. For e.g., let say that you are running following command: 
**bundle install**
Now in order to execute this command your bundle batch file should be configured correctly. By default the batch file will have somewhat like below structure:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.3.0\bin\ruby.exe" 
"C:/Users/emachnic/GitRepos/railsinstaller-windows/stage/Ruby2.3.0/bin/bundle" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"C:\Users\emachnic\GitRepos\railsinstaller-windows\stage\Ruby2.3.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %
```

For me rails is installed in **C** drive : **C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.0\bin** hence the above bundle file should be configured something like below:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe" 
"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/bundle" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %
```

This will solve the above problem.

The above solution should be applied whereever we face the problem running command.