# Rackup command not working on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rackup

I am trying to build a online chat using `private_pub` and `thin`. I have installed the gem and trying to boot thin client using below command.

```
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
```

and I am getting below error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Even `rackup --help` shows the same error. Anything to add in environment variables or `config.ru` file. Kindly help!

My platform is Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545361/rails-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified

Answer (score 1):

You should to do this

1. `gem install rack`
2. then run `rackup`

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't find `rackup` command. Add it to your `PATH` environment variable and it should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Uzbekjon!! I resolved the issue by modifying the path in C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin rackup.bat file. The path was wrongly mentioned in the file.Once I updated the correct location of rackup path, the issue is resolved.