# SSL certificate Error While installing ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed Ruby on Rails using **railsinstaller-3.2.0** [**Ruby version:2.2.4 ,Rails version : 5.0.0.1**].But while using the command  `rails new` I am confronted with an error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPwi7.png).

In addition, I am also facing another problem while using `bundle install`: it returns an exception `The system cannot find the path specified.`

[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPwi7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ssl gem source with non-ssl:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

execute above command in your command prompt.
After that

```
bundle install
```

and for creating new application please use this `rails new your_new_application_name` i,e `rails new first_app`

Comment: While I am Using 'bundle' install an exception is raised ie 'The system cannot find the path specified'.

Comment: @VARKEYVINCENT: thats another issue please refer this answer to solve that issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35680810/2681997

Comment: While every time I type 'rails new your_new_application_name'.I come up with an error for example :-An error occurred while installing turbolinks-source (5.0.0).In order to solve it 'gem install turbolinks-source -v '5.0.0''

Comment: @VARKEYVINCENT: may be this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial