# Rails - The system cannot find the path specified ( Path change fix does not work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

I have been using Rails fine but when I went to do a **Bundle install** on a new project it just will not work anymore. it wont even work on my old projects.

I have tried the solutions posted in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545361/rails-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified) but all that happens is that I do not get the error: "The system cannot find the path specified." anymore; it just hangs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it say which path is specified? or anything else?
Have you checked `gem env` to see what paths are used? have you tried uninstalling bundler and reinstalling?

Comment: Are you using the Ruby version that's default on macOS? That's generally not recommended since it can cause errors like this due to permission problems, you should use either rvm or rbenv.

Comment: **Taryn East** -  No it doesn't specify it at all it just hangs with the cursor flashing as if its executing the command, but it is not. Is uninstalling bundler an option; that might work how can I do that?

Comment: **Connor Shea** - No I am using the RailsInstaller for windows.