# rails EXECJS runtime error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hello I am getting a ExecJS::RuntimeError in Demo#index

Below is the line 6 that was highlighted and below that is my full trace.  Can someone either A: point me in the right direction to debug this as well as a good reference for debugging rails.  I am new to rails.  My guess is i'm missing a gem (i checked to make sure turbolinks was there) or something in turbolinks is wrong.  I'm using Rails 4 using rails installer (after updating gems and rails and bundle install etc.).

Below is also my gemfile

Line 6 is highlighted:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Below is my full trace:

```
execjs (1.4.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:142:in `exec_runtime'
execjs (1.4.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:28:in `block in exec'
execjs (1.4.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:41:in `compile_to_tempfile'
execjs (1.4.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `exec'
execjs (1.4.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:19:in `eval'
execjs (1.4.0) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:33:in `call'
coffee-script (2.2.0) lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.10.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.0.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:141:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.0.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:90:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.0.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:89:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.0.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:89:in `javascript_include_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__93722521_39251544'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:422:in `_run__842584183__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:654:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:366:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run__736096468__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

GEMFILE Below for this project

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: can you post your `Gemfile` and what OS are you on? Also you may find your answer on the following SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-7-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial

Comment: What is my Gemfile (sorry really enw) or do you mean just a list of gems?  As well, I am on windows 8.

Comment: Also take a look at the link I gave in my initial comment it should help you

Comment: Thanks David I am taking a look at it now

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I am also new. I must say that Ruby On Rails requires lots of patiance in learning.

Comment: @kmalik did you ever find a solution to this? Can you update the question with your solution?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and fix it :)

1. Open the `Gemfile`
2. Add below lines:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

3. Save the changes in the file
4. Execute `bundle install` on the terminal

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before and solved it by installing [node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/) (using the MSI installer).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported
>   runtimes
>
> gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby*

**remove the gem from Gemfile**

therubyracer is a embed the V8 Javascript Interpreter into Ruby

**or**

you need install Node.js

Comment: I installed Node.js and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error using Rails 5.2 and ruby 2.5. In my case the problem was with the gem Bootstrap 4. I was using `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.3'` I disabled this gem and the Rails started working. For solver the problem, I change the `gem 'bootstrap'` to `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the problem in the question is exactly the same as mine (got the same trace though). Anyway, here is one solution for execjs runtime error on Windows:
[solution by Rodrigo Argumedo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775398/javascript-include-tag-throws-unsupported-method?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This problem occurs mainly in Windows OS. Force your Coffee Script Source version to 1.8.0. Higher versions are not supported properly.

Change or add this to your gem file:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

then update the coffee-script-source bundle

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

This should fix the issue.