# javascript_include_tag throws unsupported method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I recently created a new project with Rails 4.2.0 and created a controller called `Land` for the landing page. So, I ran into this error upon visting `http://localhost:3000/land/home`:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-02-27 15:56:23 -0600
Processing by LandController#home as HTML
Rendered land/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5526ms

ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
(in C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)):
3: <head>
4:   <title>Course</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1279127835_98590860'


Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.0ms)

Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (10.0ms)

Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)

Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (2.0ms)

Rendered C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (72.0ms)
```

Is there a way of getting rid of this error? Or is it a bug?

Comment: I've had this sort of error when my js is broken. I guess the question is what js have you added? I highly doubt it's a bug.

Comment: If you think there's a problem with turbolinks, you can turn it off in your Gemfile (just remove it) and you can `bundle update` (I'm using it though and I can tell you I'm pretty confident it's working)

Comment: All I have is the application.js and the land.js.coffee at this point. I'm also doubting that is a bug. I dunno.

Comment: What's in them though? Try removing `land.js` and see whether you get that error (I'm assuming you haven't done much to `application.js`

Comment: @jcuenod Nope, both methods did not work at all.

Comment: The `js` files contain only comments. @jcuenod

Comment: I must admit, I probably can't help you with this without seeing your code - is it on github or anything? I am fairly confident this is not a bug with rails though.

Comment: @jcuenod I just pushed it to GitHub now. Feel free to mess with it. https://github.com/rodrigoargumedo/ENV-test

Comment: Have you tried removing `'data-turbolinks-track' => true`? (and the comma just before it)

Comment: Yep, It did not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recently found another solution for this problem. `gem 'coffee-script-source'` in `1.9.0` has some issues with Rails on `Windows`. I reverted to the previous version using `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` in the Gemfile, this will resolve your problem.

Another way of solving this exception is installing [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) onto your machine and the error should go away after installing & restarting `rails server`. Make sure that you add Node.js into your PATH before restarting the terminal(s) and rerun the server.

Comment: It works both ways. Although, I can put back turbolinks when `coffee-script-source` is down to 1.8.0.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked nicely. I'm also on a Windows machine.

Comment: This one solved mine too on Windows 10 computer, thanks a lot

Comment: changing coffee version encountered another problem, but installing node.js solved the problem. Note, you need to add node to PATH after you install it and then start a new command line and restart the rails server

Answer (score 4):

Ahh, it seems that you are missing

```
//= require turbolinks
```

in your application.js

See [this](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4) on removing turbolinks (and obviously make sure it's all in place if you want it running).

Comment: @jcuenod in my application.js the code you specified is availble and did not solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

I am running Windows 10, Ruby 2.1.7p400 and Rails 4.2.4.  I could not get `gem coffee-script-source '1.8.0'` to install as gem insisted on version 1.9.1.1.  I tried changing ExecJS to use UTF-8 encoding and running cscript without the //U switch as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530042/execjsruntimeerror-in-usersindex-ror) post without any luck as well.

I ended up placing nodejs.exe in the Ruby\bin folder and the issue was resolved.