# Ruby keeps giving unkown error messge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, error-handling, syntax-error

I have finally fixed most of the errors in my program, yet the Ruby on Rails command prompt keeps giving me the same error message:

```
``1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
ActionView::Template::Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property    or method
(in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-    2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `   _app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__148079984_48137160'
test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in  <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


2) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact:
ActionView::Template::Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property   or method
(in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__148079984_48137160'
test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:23:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


 3) Error:
 StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
 ActionView::Template::Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support this   property or method
 (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
 app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__148079984_48137160'
 test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


 4) Error:
 StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
 ActionView::Template::Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
 (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
 app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__148079984_48137160'
 test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

How do I get past this problem? I can't advance into my application without fixing this.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Please show your `Gemfile` and `application.js` file.

Comment: I am on Windows, but at the moment there is no application.js file for my rails app. The gemfile cannot be shown in the comments.

Comment: Windows has a known issue (with `gem 'coffee-script-source' in 1.9.0`). See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29609359/981183
This should fix your problem too...

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely *coffee-script* version 1.9.0+ gem  error, use `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` (place it in your Gemfile). Don't forgot to run **bundle**

Comment: Won't that compromise the program. I'm just asking because I don't want to make any more damage to the program.

Comment: No. It will use another version of `coffee-script` gem.

Comment: Ok, so it updated coffee-script-source, but now it's giving me four failures.

Comment: @metaco57 - Do they fail with the same error message? BTW - abandon windows, it will make your developer's live miserable.

Comment: You mean I should switch to Ubuntu or another Linux OS?

Comment: I don't know any good rails developer using Windows. It is because some gems wouldn't even work on Windows