# Rails Action controller: Exception caught

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I get this error in the heading of my application.html.erb file

```
ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Cet objet ne gère pas cette propriété ou cette méthode):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>LifeHacks</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___906694100_51941424'
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to fix this? Thanks.

The exception I get well error is

ExecJS::ProgramError in Homepage#index

Here is my homepagecontroller

```
 class HomepageController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

and lastly here is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "homepage#index"

end
```

I do have a turbolinks gem added

Comment: do you have turbolinks gem?

Comment: I do have a turbolinks gem

Comment: So the translation of the exception is: "Object does not support this property or method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on Windows? If so, your question might be solved by using a different version coffee-script-source (1.8.0 instead of 1.9.0) as shown here: [javascript_include_tag throws unsupported method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775398/javascript-include-tag-throws-unsupported-method)