# Image files in Rails app disappear after subsequent pushes to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

I am seeing something odd in my Rails app, which is using a gem / [blog engine called Line](https://github.com/opoloo/lines-engine) for blog posts. In those blog posts, you can upload images in line, and those images are stored in a table `LinesPicture`.

Everything is fine locally, and it works when I push live to Heroku. In other words, I can write three blogs with pictures in each blog post, those images are stored in `LinesPicture` table, and they load normally.

Then, if I push anything from local branch to Heroku thereafter, the images no longer show in the post and the error `[Alt Text]` comes instead.

Checking the source of the post, it is still linked to the internal image file:

```
<div class="article_content">    
        <p><p><img src="/uploads/lines/picture/image/5/aac_divisions.png" alt="Alt Text"/></p>
```

I assumed this meant the image was no longer in the table, but if I run `heroku run rails console` and then `LinesPicture.last`, the image is definitely still there:

```
LinesPicture.last
  LinesPicture Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "lines_pictures".* FROM "lines_pictures"  ORDER BY "lines_pictures"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<LinesPicture id: 5, image: "aac_divisions.png", name: "Aac Divisions", article_id: 1, created_at: "2017-08-19 21:15:42", updated_at: "2017-08-19 21:15:48">
```

So in short, the image is loading, subsequent pushes are causing an issue, and yet the image file ("aac_divisions.png") is still stored in the table.

Last step, I tried running `heroku logs` but didn't see anything useful. Concludes with:

```
 request_id=5d89a754-429a-46f8-9238-52f1108849ed fwd="98.234.48.100" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=404 bytes=1829 protocol=https
2017-08-19T21:38:08.487398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/uploads/lines/picture/image/5/aac_divisions.png" host=quiet-coast-71929.herokuapp.com request_id=a6af52fa-a86d-4008-a924-6e68a307b9af fwd="98.234.48.100" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=404 bytes=1829 protocol=https
2017-08-19T21:41:52.151184+00:00 heroku[run.8811]: State changed from up to complete
2017-08-19T21:41:52.138358+00:00 heroku[run.8811]: Process exited with status 0
```

Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

In `production.rb` change

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

If you are using Rails 4 or an even earlier version Rails, you must add `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` into your Gemfile in order for Heroku to serve your static assets.

If you are using Rails 5 this gem is not needed.  From Heroku:

> Previous versions of Rails required you to add a gem to your project
>   rails_12factor to enable static asset serving and logging on Heroku.
>   If you are deploying a new application this gem is not needed. If you
>   are upgrading an existing application you can remove this gem provided
>   you have the appropriate configuration in your
>   config/environments/production.rb file

Finally push to heroku again.

Comment: Made the change but generated a new error: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
No such middleware to insert before: ActionDispatch::Static`. Working through why the rake is filing now. Will report back if I figure it out.

Comment: hmm.. see what happens when you change `config.serve_static_assets = false
` to `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your production.rb.

Comment: Yes, was trying that after I saw the error. Seems to cause: `ExecJS::RuntimeError: 
(execjs):1`, and I am reading through some Stack Overflow questions on why that would happen.

Comment: Update: Followed the second answer here. Installed two gems, and now it runs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051358/rails-execjs-runtime-error

Comment: Last Update: Good news, it was able to run after installing those gems. Unfortunately after pushing to Heroku, the problem still persists. Must be something else. Thank you though.

Comment: Ok, got it. The trick is that you also need to add `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` into your gemfile, per Heroku's documentation. Seems to be working now. Can you update your answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: Ah, yes... you're right.  I forgot to mention the 12factor gem.  Are you using Rails 5?  I believe that it's no longer necessary to install the gem anymore with 5 (I think).  Otherwise Heroku requires it.