# Rails link_to method: :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am sorry for asking what may be a remedial question, but in learning rails i was trying to follow along note for note in this tutorial:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I posted a similar question from this tutorial last night and got a prompt response which helped me significantly, so I am hoping for the same.  Thank you in advance.

Section 5.14: Deleting Posts

I am instructed to add a delete link to the index.html.erb page

```
<h1>Listing Posts</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.text %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

which generates:

```
<td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/posts/1" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
```

It looks OK to me, but when I click on the link I get neither the confirmation nor am I directed to the delete action.  It generates this HTTP action

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/posts/1 
Request Method:GET 
Status Code:200 OK
```

Rails: 4, Ruby: 2, 64 bit windows 8, chrome: Version 28.0.1500.72 m

Thank you again

---

Adding the application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Listing</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

which yielded this error:

> ExecJS::RuntimeError in Posts#index Showing
>   C:/Ruby-Projects/listing/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where
>   line #6 raised:
>
> (in
>   C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-1.3.0/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee) Extracted source (around line #6): 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>                
>       Listing
>       <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
>       <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
>       <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
>
> Rails.root: C:/Ruby-Projects/listing
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___567964991_28724900' Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> None

---

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Do you have `<%= javascript_include_tag :applicaton %>` in your layout?

Comment: When I add it, it gives me an error

Comment: Make sure your `JavaScript` is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK i needed to remove  these two lines from application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

which got rid of the ExecJS run time error.  Why were these included by default, and should I be figuring out why they were causing an error in the first place?

FWIW - the delete functionality now works.

---

Props to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-7-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

into application.js file and application.js file is included into `view/layout/application.html.erb`file

Comment: I think I have the included in application.js, how do I assure that application.js is included through application.erb?

Comment: Add this line `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>` into `application.html.erb` file

Answer (score 2):

my product application have this listed js files.

would you please check wheather you have all the files in assets folder.

which autoloads your post controller called.

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/products.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/say.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now see my index.erb.html files

```
<h1>Listing products</h1>

<table>
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Image url</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd','list_line_even') %>">
<td><%= product. title %></td>
<td><%= product.description %></td>
<td><%= product.image_url %></td>
<td><%= product.price %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
%></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br/>

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

Comment: hey @supercool I downvoted this completely on accident!!  I didn't realize it until just now, and apparently I cant undo my downvote until an edit is made.... not trying to hurt your S.O. cred, so maybe you can make a minimal edit (add a random space etc) and I can clear my downvote.