# Rails 5.1.6 issues with assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I recently installed rails 5.1.6 but when I go to any one of the views in an application, it throws the following error.

```
Errno::ENOENT in Test#index

No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Bastian/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20180513-17244-1f5fvjjson

Started GET "/test/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-13 20:22:07 -0400
Processing by TestController#index as HTML
Rendering test/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered test/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Access Denied.
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 427ms
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Bastian/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20180513-17244-1f5fvjjson):
4:     <title>Testr</title>
5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
6:
7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
9:   </head>
10:
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__530887143_69788540'
```

I've been looking everywhere but haven't found a solution.
I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I figured out how to get rid of the error thanks to this answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748774/8048737

In resume I deleted these two lines from ***application.js***:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```