# Local rails instance errors on turbolinks call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have just set up a new Rails 4 instance and scaffolded out a user class.

Whenever I try and navigate to any of the scaffolded pages, I get an internal 500 error:

```
Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-11 18:57:28 +1000
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1585ms

ActionView::Template::Error (
  (in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-1.3.0/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>GlueFactory</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1232737741_41577300'
```

I have the turbolinks 1.3.0 gem installed. If I remove the line <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %> from application.html.erb as indicated by the stack trace, it works OK.

I figure this must be an issue with my gem environment as I have uploaded this to Heroku and it runs OK from there with the turbolinks line included.

bundle show:

- actionmailer (4.0.0)
- actionpack (4.0.0)
- activemodel (4.0.0)
- activerecord (4.0.0)
- activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
- activesupport (4.0.0)
- arel (4.0.0)
- atomic (1.1.12)
- builder (3.1.4)
- bundler (1.3.5)
- coffee-rails (4.0.0)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- hike (1.2.3)
- i18n (0.6.4)
- jbuilder (1.5.0)
- jquery-rails (3.0.4)
- json (1.8.0)
- mail (2.5.4)
- mime-types (1.23)
- minitest (4.7.5)
- multi_json (1.7.8)
- pg (0.16.0)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rack (1.5.2)
- rack-test (0.6.2)
- rails (4.0.0)
- railties (4.0.0)
- rake (10.1.0)
- rdoc (3.12.2)
- sass (3.2.10)
- sass-rails (4.0.0)
- sdoc (0.3.20)
- sprockets (2.10.0)
- sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
- thor (0.18.1)
- thread_safe (0.1.2)
- tilt (1.4.1)
- treetop (1.4.14)
- turbolinks (1.3.0)
- tzinfo (0.3.37)
- uglifier (2.1.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too have seen this error.  It is an encoding issue with execjs.  I found the solution on this thread ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial))    I opted for the third option - much more satisfying!

Comment: It is better to also include the relevant code in your answer rather than only link to the another post.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem  on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
rake about
```

reported that node js was found.

```
which node
```

gave

```
/usr/sbin/node
```

which was actually a symlink to **ax25-node**.

Basically, rails was reporting that it found an executable with the name **node** on the path and was assuming that it was **nodejs**.

After I uninstalled the packages **node** and **ax52-node** and installed the **nodejs** 
package, the problem went away.

In windows, nodejs executable is named **node**. On a Linux system - at least on the version of ubuntu I have installed - the name of the 
executable is nodejs. I believe the reason for the error is that no suitable 
JavaScript interpreter could be found during runtime.

I hope it helps someone.