# Ruby on Rails ExecJS::RuntimeError in Pages#home

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I generated a page using a controller. But when I go to the localhost:3000/pages/home. I got this error:
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Pages#home

@RyanBigg Okay here is the full error code:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Pages#home

Showing C:/Users/Anishka/Desktop/test/myfirstapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:


  (in C:/Users/Anishka/Desktop/test/myfirstapp/app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <head>
4:   <title>Myfirstapp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
Rails.root: C:/Users/Anishka/Desktop/test/myfirstapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__601430158_32305500'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

I found a solution from here [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

which is:

> The Fix that worked for us: On the system having issues, find ExecJS's
>   runtimes.rb file. It looks like this. Make a copy of the found file
>   for backup. Open the original runtimes.rb for editing. Find the
>   section that starts with the line JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(. In
>   that section, on the line containing :command => "cscript //E:jscript
>   //Nologo //U", - remove the //U only. Then on the line containing
>   :encoding => 'UTF-16LE' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE - change
>   UTF-16LE to UTF-8 . Save the changes to the file. This section of the
>   file should now read:
>
> JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
>       :name        => "JScript",
>       :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
>       :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
>       :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE ) Next, stop then restart your Rails server and refresh the page in your
>   browser that produced the original error. Hopefully the page loads
>   without error now.

But where is the runtimes.rb file? I could not find anything like that. I'm rails beginner and your help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ExecJS supports these runtimes:

   ` therubyracer - Google V8 embedded within Ruby
    therubyrhino - Mozilla Rhino embedded within JRuby
    Node.js
    Apple JavaScriptCore - Included with Mac OS X
    Microsoft Windows Script Host (JScript)`

Comment: did you install `therubyracer` gem

Comment: Please show us the full error message. You're missing a part of it from your post.

Comment: Hello, I'm using a simple package from here http://railsinstaller.org/en

apart from that I've not installed anything else.

Comment: @RajarshiDas I'm using rails installer. It comes with all the things, I guess. but therubyracer gem is required? and how can I check if I've already installed that gem in my system? thanks.

Comment: @RyanBigg  I posted the full error code above.

Comment: do cd rails_app && `bundle show therubyracer` or `gem list therubyracer`

Comment: @RajarshiDas  you mean go to my app directory from cmd and then type bundle show therubyracer, right? I did that and it says: Could not find gem 'therubyracer'.

Are you sure, I need that gem in my system? If yes, then how can I install it?

Also, where the gems stored? in folders? or they are stored in my app only?

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: thats mean you did not install the rubyracer which will require please follow https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows

Comment: @RajarshiDas I installed it using cmd but there is one more step, it says Copy v8.dll & v8preparser.dll in to ruby\bin folder. Where is the ruby/bin folder? I checked my app folders, it's not there!

Comment: @RajarshiDas I copied those dll files to C:/Rails Installer/Ruby/bin folder. When I enter "bundle show therubyracer" it shows the same message - could not find gem. And when I use "gem list therubyracer" it shows this:     *** LOCAL GEMS ***

therubyracer (0.11.0beta1 x86-mingw32)
    
I stopped the rails server by using Ctrl+C and started again, refreshed the page but still shows the same error!

Comment: app/assets/javascripts/ Please change the page extension pages.js.coffee to page.js.jsx

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the command line ExecJS uses for cscript.  This can be done in the gem's runtimes.rb file.  For me, this was located in:

> C:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\execjs-2.0.2\lib\execjs

Naturally, that'll be different depending on your version of Ruby and where it's installed.

I found this workaround in [a thread for an ExecJS issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/81#issuecomment-5807329).

I changed this:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
  :name        => "JScript",
  :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U",
  :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
  :encoding    => 'UTF-16LE' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

to this:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
  :name        => "JScript",
  :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
  :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
  :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

This screenshot is also from that thread:

[image: screenshot]