# rails generate controller pages generates but local host doesn't show new home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with "One month rails" (rails 4), used 'rails generate controller pages home' for new home page. It all seems fine but the local host page is still stating "welcome aboard
You’re riding Ruby on Rails!" and not the new home page as expected. any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Delete the default page i.e, public/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: 'pages#home'
```

Comment: Thanks. did that but I get this error: ExecJS::RuntimeError in Pages#home Extracted source (around line #6):
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
          
  <head>
    <title>Pinteresting</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>   . tried using this answer-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial - no luck.

Comment: We have solved the current issue. Need go deeper. Could you show the full listing of the errror?

Comment: Thanks and Yes. I get **ExecJS::RuntimeError in Pages#home **  , Extracted source (around line #6):   
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
          
  <head>  
    <title>Pinteresting</title>  
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

Comment: also- removing the line //= require_tree . from application.js didn't work.

Comment: add in `Gemfile` the following line `gem 'therubyracer'` then run `bundle install`

Comment: thank you. had trouble with the  gem rubytracer, it couldn't be installed and bundle on my computer, but it works fine on cloud IDE.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 steps that should be done:

- map the new controller and action to your `root_path` in your config routes (as [itsnikolay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125940/687142) suggests )
- remove the default index page `public/index.html` (as [ardochhigh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125955/687142) suggests)
- restart you development server

Answer (score 0):

You should change your "root" mapping realtionship in config/routes.rb. Make sure "root" point to the page (controller#action) you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the default index page.

Go to your Rails root directory and delete public/index.html

```
rm public/index.html
```

Comment: This is described as a Rails 4 app in the original post