# ExecJS::RuntimeError - Rails 4 - Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, runtime-error

When I run my rails app, I've got this huge error :

[image]
[image]

Here my application.hmtl.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>  
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
</body>
```

My gemfile.lock:

```
    GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.3)
      activemodel (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.15)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2-x86-mingw32)
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.10)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.15.2)
      timers (~> 1.1.0)
    celluloid-io (0.15.0)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.0)
      nio4r (>= 0.5.0)
    childprocess (0.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.3-x86-mingw32)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    guard (2.5.1)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.6)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-rspec (2.5.0)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      rspec (~> 2.11)
    guard-spork (1.5.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.3)
      guard (>= 1.1)
      spork (>= 0.8.4)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    listen (2.7.1)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      celluloid-io (>= 0.15.0)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.9.0)
    nio4r (1.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.1-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)
    polyglot (0.3.4)
    pry (0.9.12.6-x86-mingw32)
      coderay (~> 1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
      win32console (~> 1.3)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
    rb-inotify (0.9.3)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rb-notifu (0.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.3.3)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (< 1.0.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    slop (3.5.0)
    spork (1.0.0rc4-x86-mingw32)
      win32-process
    spork-rails (4.0.0)
      rails (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      spork (>= 1.0rc0)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.2.0)
      atomic (>= 1.1.7, < 2)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (2.2.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.39)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    will_paginate (3.0.4)
    win32-process (0.7.4)
      ffi (>= 1.0.0)
    win32console (1.3.2-x86-mingw32)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.1.2)
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.1.0)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 0.0.10)
  capybara (= 2.1.0)
  childprocess (= 0.4.0)
  coffee-rails (= 4.0.1)
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.2.1)
  faker (= 1.1.2)
  guard-rspec (= 2.5.0)
  guard-spork (= 1.5.0)
  jbuilder (= 1.0.2)
  jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)
  pg (= 0.15.1)
  rails (= 4.0.3)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rb-notifu (= 0.0.4)
  rspec-rails (= 2.13.1)
  sass-rails (= 4.0.1)
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  selenium-webdriver (= 2.35.1)
  spork-rails (= 4.0.0)
  sprockets (= 2.11.0)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.8)
  therubyracer
  turbolinks (= 2.2.1)
  uglifier (= 2.1.1)
  will_paginate (= 3.0.4)
```

I **already tried** :

- Install NodeJS (same error)
- Modified the file runtimes.rb
- Install therubyracer (look up my gemfile.lock)

Runtimes.rb :

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
    :name        => "JScript",
    :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
    :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
    :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

What should I do ?

---

Comment: Have you tried looking at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14118913/1905235

Comment: I did, that's why I tried to install nodeJs and modified the file runtimes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolved" the problem, I formated my laptop and installed Windows 7 Ultimate...