# ExecJS::Runtime Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial (chapter 3, 3.1).  After running "rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework", I navigated to /static_pages/home.  And I get this error message below.

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in StaticPages#home
Showing C:/Sites/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

(in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks 1.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):

3  <head>
4    <title>SampleApp</title>
5    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
6    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
7    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8  </head>
9  <body>
```

Here is the framework trace

```
execjs (2.2.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:152:in `exec_runtime'
execjs (2.2.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:29:in `exec'
execjs (2.2.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:18:in `eval'
execjs (2.2.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:36:in `call'
coffee-script (2.2.0) lib/coffee_script.rb:57:in `compile'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/coffee.rb:46:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:144:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:91:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:90:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:90:in `javascript_include_tag'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__687102642__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__624948244__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Please let me know if you need any more file/code, I'm a RoR beginner and not quite sure what to post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Comment: Please look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14118913/2456549. I edited these files last week for a co-worker and it works fine now. If you go into execjs's `runtime.rb` file, and change those lines, it should work. This problem is happening a lot on Windows.

Comment: I have 3 runtimes.rb files.  One under execjs 1.4.0, execjs 2.2.0 and execjs 2.2.1; which one should I edit?

Comment: Check which version is locked in Gemfile.lock

Comment: I actually ended up editing all 3 of them and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this answer: [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial/14118913#14118913).

I edited these files last week for a co-worker and it works fine now. If you go into execjs's `runtimes.rb` file, and change those lines, it should work. This problem is happening a lot on Windows.