# ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable in Rails 4.1.4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, execjs

**UPDATE** : Things are now working !

Thanks to [deep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2300000/deep), I installed node.js then got a TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error wich got resolved by adding `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]` and `bundle update`.

Thank you sir !

---

First of all, I am a complete beginner on rails (just so that you get how beginner I am : I feel as being an expert for just posting here) and this is my first question here so please excuse me if I'm not very clear.

So, I am a windows 7 user, learning rails with the One Month course and I encounter an error while trying to :

```
$ rake routes
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://git
hub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
c:/Users/Marc Montagne/Desktop/pinteresting/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (re
quired)>'
c:/Users/Marc Montagne/Desktop/pinteresting/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

or

```
$ rails server
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.4.0
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.4.0
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from c:/Users/Marc Montagne/Desktop/pinteresting/config/application.rb:7
:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

All that I understand is that I have a problem with ExecJS. As a total beginner I don't even know what ExecJS is.

I read the great thread [#12520456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial/14118913#14118913) and while editing runtimes.rb didn't fix my problem, it still gave me a better understanding of the situation and the willingness to solve my problem by fixing it and not "ignoring it" by adding node.js especially given the fact that I could run my server before and that I want to fix what I basically broke.

What I mean by that is that I think I did something wrong when editing the PATH (I don't even know what this is) of my Windows environment for fixing an issue I had with installing Heroku. I remember editing that part as I read it somewhere and while it seemed to have fixed my Heroku issue I think it messed up the rest.

Thank you in advance for your help and understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Comment: I guess the best way to fix the problem is to install a js runtime like node.js.

Comment: @deep : i'm okay to give it a shot, could you please me guide me through the steps as I'm a total beginner ? Thanks again

Comment: Sure Which Operating System Are You Using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 !

Comment: Just download the installer package from http://nodejs.org/ and install. Also you may need to restart your system so that rails can pick it up

Comment: @AlphonseJr Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows this should help you resolve the problem.

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu Users

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and had similar issues. Installing Node.js fixed it.

As of Ubuntu 13.04 x64 you only need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This will solve the problem.
CentOS/RedHat Users

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

Comment: I would recommend installing node using nvm rather than just installing node using apt, e.g. https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/

Answer (score 5):

A quick and easy solution is to uncomment this line in Gemfile and run `bundle install` again

```
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

Comment: Hello Santosh. The line wasn't in my Gemfile (not even commented) so I manually added it and did the bundle install but I keep getting my error message.

Comment: @Santosh...good answer. But I have had a few people get this error. This solution weirdly only helped resolve a few of the issues.

Comment: No, linux. Ubuntu to be precise.

Comment: Yep I *think* that's why. I believe the solution above worked on my virtual machine running linux, but when using Windows, ugh, the only solution was to edit the `runtimes.rb` file. :)

Comment: I am using windows 7 and I tried editing the runtimes.rb file. Isn't more an issue with a "path" ?

Comment: This is not a good answer because therubyracer is discouraged to be used in production.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in great detail by @KevinP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14118913/2456549).

Following the link above, you need to go into Execjs's `runtimes.rb` and change that line specified in his answer. After that, restart your server and it should start working.

The block that needs to be changed looks like this:

```
JScript = ExternalRuntime.new(
  :name        => "JScript",
  :command     => "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo",
  :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/jscript_runner.js",
  :encoding    => 'UTF-8' # CScript with //U returns UTF-16LE
)
```

^ Credit to [Kevin P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1942106/kevin-p).

I also answered this question a few days go here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591983/2456549

Comment: Hello Justin, as said in my question, I've already been through the thread you indicate and did the runtimes.rb change with no results...
My error message is ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable and not ExecJS::RuntimeError as in the other thread. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RedDeath answer, here is the way to go for Alpine users:

```
apk add nodejs
```

That solved the error for me.