# Installing rails for first time and cant connect to server

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems

I'm just starting out trying to learn to code and I'm trying to get Ruby running for my first time. Ive been searching for over an hour and can't find a solution. When I try to connect to the server i get this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could
not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS:
:RuntimeUnavailable)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (requir
ed)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `requi
re'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block
 (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block
 in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `requi
re'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/railsbridge/test_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:79:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:79:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.
rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top
(required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Then when I try to install `execjs`  and then  `execjs --source http://rubygems.org` the following happens:

> C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>gem install execjs ERROR:  Could not
>   find a valid gem 'execjs' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https:// rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read serv er certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed (https://
>   api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
>
> C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>gem install execjs --source http://
>   rubygems.org Successfully installed execjs-2.2.2  Parsing
>   documentation for execjs-2.2.2 Done installing documentation for
>   execjs after 0 seconds WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://
>   rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server
>   certificate B: certificate verify failed
>   (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz) 1 gem installed

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm running on Windows 7 as well.

Update: execjs installed ok. But when i install  therubyracer i get this:

C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>gem install therubyracer
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150127-8476-14s0h51.rb extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:68:in `setup_python!': li
bv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in`block
 in build_libv8!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:49:in `chdir
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:49:in`build
_libv8!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `inst
all!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in`'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7 for inspect
ion.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/libv8-3.16.14.7/gem_
make.out

C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app>

ps: sorry about my format I'm trying to learn how to use it properly

Comment: You need the `nodejs` gem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609912/execjsruntimeunavailable-in-rails-4-1-4)

Comment: It seems you are using windows OS, So go to this link http://railsinstaller.org/en and download full bundle, it will install all the dependencies to run a rails server, although installing nodejs will solve this problem.

Comment: I originally installed ruby and rails from railsinstaller.org.  I also just installed node gem, but I still get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in gem file

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```