# ruby on rails - can't run javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and am
stuck at destroying the article. It won't bring up the dialog to delete but just redirects to the article. Can someone help me delete the article? I know it has to do with javascript but can't figure out. Thanks in advance.

These are my settings:

GEMFILE

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
#gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'execjs'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
...
```

application.html.erb

```
...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
...
```

javascript line gave me an execjs error in browser so I changed 'application' to 'default' and it was ok.

application.js

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

index.html.erb

```
...    
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      ...
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: `:defaults`, not `'default'` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers.html) You need to include the proper files and fix the js errors..

Comment: changed 'default' to :defaults but it didn't work. also re-installed execjs by 'gem install execjs' and it still doesn't work. I'm using windows, rails version is 4.2.3. Zoran's link seems to be for older versions but I tried everything to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial I'm fresh out of close votes for today, but I bet this is what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already have:

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'execjs'
```

in your Gemfile.

You should just run:

`bundle install`

to install the gems and re-start the server.
Everything should work afterwords!

Alternatively, just install another Javascript runtime library such as [Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) and it should work!

### Update

Replace `defaults` with `application` in your `application.html.erb` file and add: `gem 'coffee-script-source'` to your Gemfile and run: `bundle install`

Your problem should be fixed by now.

Comment: commented out gem 'therubyracer' as it seems it's not recommended anymore. 'bundle install' doesn't do anything. it just says 'using ...' and doesn't update. execjs is 2.5.2. How do I install node.js?

Comment: Are you on Mac OSX? You can follow this link to install node js: https://changelog.com/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x/
Here is another link which will be helpful for installing node js: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: Sorry. On Windows 8 64-bit.

Comment: You should be able to install Node.js on your Windows 8 computer following the instructions from this link: http://blog.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/2013/10/24/installing-node-js-on-windows-8/
Let me know if that helps.

Comment: ok I installed node.js and it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Did you restart the Rails server? Does it still show the same error?

Comment: Yes I rebooted the computer after installing node.js and reopened the cmd prompt to enter 'rails s'. What frustrates me is I don't know what's happening beyond it that I can't troubleshoot. I've been just doing what people are saying, eg take this off, take that off.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the exact error messages. This link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial
has some solid discussions on windows platform. You can take a look and see if any one of those work for you. Also, I am on Mac OSX. So, I can't test or reproduce your problem locally.

Comment: saw this in console:   Started GET "/javascripts/defaults.js" for ::1 at 2015-08-09 16:33:33 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/defaults.js
"):

Comment: replace `defaults ` with  `application ` in your `application.html.erb` file and add `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. Then try again.

Comment: I edited the gemfile and when I bundle install, I get this msg "The bundle currently has coffee-script-source locked at 1.9.1.1.
Try running `bundle update coffee-script-source`" Also, after reading [http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers.html#method-i-javascript_include_tag], I notice that I don't have any javascript folder in public folder. Is this ok?

Comment: ok I did the 'bundle update coffee-script-source' and changed to 'application' and it worked. I don't know what triggered it exactly. It may have been the gem coffee-script-source command. Thank you K M Rakibul Islam.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you :)
Could you please accept my answer now?