# Rails 4 newbe : Routing Error -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I am very new to rails. No idea how to fix it. I cannot even start a simple rails app!

```
Environment:
    Windows 7
    Ruby 2.1.0
    Rails 4.2.3
```

First: I ran generate command

D:\railprojects\blog>rails generate controller Pages index

**routes.rb**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/index'

end
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Pages#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/index.html.erb</p>
```

I am getting following error.

**http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages**

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/pages"

Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
pages_index_path    GET /pages/index(.:format)  pages#index
Request

Parameters:

None
```

**Screenshot**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/06W5e.jpg

Please help. If you need more info, please let me know.

**localhost:3000/pages/index**

**changed to - get 'pages#index'**

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/pages"

Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.
For more information about routes, please see the Rails guide Rails Routing from the Outside In.
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url
```

**Change it to  - resources :pages**

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index
Showing D:/railprojects/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2066577970_70340560'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"




Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages', to: 'pages#index'
end



ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index
Showing D:/railprojects/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2066577970_70340560'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
Response

Headers:

None
```

**changed to**

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'pages', to: 'pages#index'
    end
```

/

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index
Showing D:/railprojects/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2066577970_70340560'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate, sdch"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6"
REMOTE_ADDR: "127.0.0.1"
REMOTE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
Response

Headers:

None
```

Comment: you should replace existing line with this in your routes file `get 'pages/', to: 'pages#index`

Comment: For ExecJS error , take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial) ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, dont use Windows to developing in Rails... YOu will have a lot of headaches. Believe in me.

If you dont want to install Linux (like ubuntu), you can use vagrant (https://www.vagrantup.com/).

About your error, you defined `pages/index` route, but you are trying to visit `pages` route.

What you can is, is define the `pages`route, like:

```
get 'pages', to: 'pages#index'
```

with that, you can visit you page  in this way: `http://localhost:3000/pages`which will send you to `PagesController` and `index` action.

About another error: ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index Showing ...

- You need a javascript runtime, like: NodeJS - https://nodejs.org/ installed.

Comment: Hi, did that as Pawel suggested. no luck. Seems I have to install Ubuntu!

Comment: @Khoga did restart the server after install NodeJS ? maybe you need to restart Windows too

Comment: Hi, how to install nodejs? gem install nodejs ??

Comment: Installed Rails on Ubuntu and everything fine! not going to to use Windows.A huge thanks to @Paweł Dawczak. Sorry I could not mark both of you correct.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
localhost:3000/pages/index
```

or if you want to go on index page with this localhost:3000/pages change routes

```
resources :pages
```

Comment: Hi, changes that but still shows error. Due to stackoverflow rule I could not attached the screen shot but here is the error.                 ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index
Showing D:/railprojects/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2066577970_70340560'
Request

Parameters:

None

Answer (score 0):

You should point

```
http://localhost:3000/pages/index
```

in your browser to reach proper action.

This is because of your route configuration:

```
get 'pages/index'
```

If you would like to be able to point `/pages`, you have to reconfigure it to look like:

```
get 'pages', to: 'pages#index'
```

You can find more about Rails routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html);

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

The whole content of `config/routes.rb` should look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages', to: 'pages#index'
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. But it still shows error                        ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#index
Showing D:/railprojects/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2066577970_70340560'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump

Comment: Hi, changed it to  get pages#index, but still shows error Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/pages"

Rails.root: D:/railprojects/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.
For more information about routes, please see the Rails guide Rails Routing from the Outside In.
Helper HTTP Verb Path Controller#Action
Path / Url

Comment: @Khoga, it's very difficult to read the stack trace from comments, could you update your question with this information?

Comment: Ok, my apologies @Khoga, I'm afraid I've confused you a bit... Please check my answer updated, so you can find the content of whole `config/routes.rb`