# execjs (LoadError) on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, execjs

i have spend days trying to fix this bloody error but still unsuccessful, i have tried all the solutions i could on stackoverflow and other sites. I have downloaded and installed nodejs, just so that you know.

here is the error trace:

C:\Sites\RDB>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/cof
fee_script.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- execjs (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-script-
2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-4
.1.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-4
.1.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/
lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/RDB/config/application.rb:11:in`'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in`block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
        from bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from bin/rails:9:in`'

Comment: i have tried adding rubyracer gem, that gave asked me to add libv8, which i was never able to install even with -- --with-system-v8 command

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, the error is gone! I feel RailsInstaller need to come up with a solutions or else beginners like me will all have to face this nightmare if they are using windows

[ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

1) Removing  //= require_tree . / Ignoring the issue - As ColinR stated above, this line should not be causing an issue in the first place. There is an actual problem with ExecJS working properly with the JavaScript runtime on your system and removing this line is just ignoring that fact.