# hello world rails app error object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a simple Hello World app using rails on my Windows 10 machine. Attached is a screenshot of the error message I'm receiving when I view my app at local.host.3000 and the corresponding supposed error. I believe the error is linked to a missing download on my computer, because the part of the code at fault was generated for me, without my tampering with it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to run `bundle install` after successful `rails new` on your terminal/command prompt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)