# ActionView: :Template: :Error Object not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have been struggling to find an answer to this question, obviously I haven't done it yet. I tried coding my first little bit, I can open the server with no problem but as I open it, but insted of showing me what I coded, the server tells me:
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Extracted source (around line #7):

```
    CTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Programar101</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my command prompt, when the error occurs, it gives me this:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method):
    4:     <title>APP</title>
    5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    6:
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    9:   </head>
   10:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__332994069_78270120'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (60.1ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (32.6ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (5146.8ms)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Given the error is coming from the stylesheet inclusion line, can you add your stylesheet to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial) has some good details into understanding the problem. I had the exact issue and followed the stack trace and it seemed the cause is from `execjs`. However what differs is that changing `runtimes.rb` does NOT fix the issue. Removing the `//= require_tree .` does fix but that is not right solution either as it is quick fix.

One working good solution is to install Node and I [have heard](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/issues/81#issuecomment-9892952) this fixes the problem. I can confirm this fixed the problem for me. I think it has to do with the `runtimes.rb` file and how the default JS env on Windows sucks.

Comment: it's not the same error, so I doubt the fix will be the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's same error because My error is same as this one in that the stylesheet has problems loading but when I remove the `//= require_tree .` from `application.js` the problem goes away. The quick fix solution is identical.

Comment: That's another way to avoid the problem without actually fixing it. If you want JavaScript in your app, don't do that.

Comment: Ok I changed my answer quite a bit after trying a few more things and clarifying. Pls no downvote, I try my best

Answer (score -2):

You need to change 'application' to 'default' in lines 6 and 7.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: This is plainly wrong. The error will go away, but now you'll have no stylesheets/JavaScript in your app.