# jQuery is not defined,$ is not defined,Rails is not defined in windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin, rails-administrate

[image]

**When I load localhost:3000/admin I keep getting this message in the Chrome dev tools, and my RailsAdmin is then broken without jQuery**

I am getting an error in my console

```
'JQuery is not defined'
'$ is not defined'
'Rails admin is not defined'.
```

---

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

i have this gem, also i done bundle install

Default file present in \app\assets\javascripts\application.rb

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Then i change file  \app\assets\javascripts\rails_admin\rails_admin.rb

```
//= require 'jquery2'
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

even i also tried this things

```
//= require jquery2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

then

```
//= require 'jquery2'
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

everything i tried, still getting error in my browser console

But, it's worked on mac it's working perfectly,windows getting troble to me

Comment: Not activeadmin

Answer (score 0):

I think your file called `app\assets\javascripts\rails_admin\rails_admin.js` instead of `.rb`
You shouldn't to rewrite this file, just add to manifest additional dependencies. Because jquery is required by [gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/dca8911f240ea11ebb186c33573188aa9e1b031d/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/rails_admin.js).

As you see `rails_admin.js` load tons of dependencies by his own. So if you rewrite this file you will brake some gem functionality.

Comment: Thanks your help! but got error like this TypeError: **Object doesn't support this property or method**  '    begin
          extract_result(@runtime.exec_runtime(filepath), filepath)
        ensure
          File.unlink(tmpfile)
        end
'

Comment: Well i can't help you in this way, try removving all your own dependencies and start from bear `rails_admin`. It should have jqeury by it self, and then start adding. By the way version conflict is possible if you require `jquery2`, when `jquery` already loaded, so be careful.

Comment: thank for your help nautgrad,i have created new rails_admin ,there is no dependencies and also getting same error,may be it's neither gem or version problem

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. I just created new rails app added `rails_admin` and started server. jQuery loaded. See [screenshot](https://snag.gy/p8k5vS.jpg).

Comment: When I load localhost:3000/admin I keep getting this message in the Chrome dev tools, and my RailsAdmin is then broken without jQuery ,so it's might be my problem !         @@  **which version are you using rails**   my version is 5.0.2

Comment: I have `4.2.7.1` because 5 rails is quite raw in my opinion. I didn't find any mentions that `rails_admin` supports rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this solution, this might work in most of the cases,

[Rails on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Comment: I tried everything,it's doen't work. Do you have other solution for this...

Comment: After removing //= require_tree , can you post the error what you getting?

Comment: my rails_admin is working perfectly,When I load localhost:3000/admin I keep getting this message in the Chrome dev tools, and my RailsAdmin is then broken without jQuery