# Ruby on Rails v5.1.1 Home Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting to develop in RoR and I have found the following problem:

[Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTXyw.jpg)

The command prompt:

```
Started GET "/pages/inicio" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-22 22:43:24 -0300
Processing by PagesController#inicio as HTML
  Rendering pages/inicio.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/inicio.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 844ms

ActionView::Template::Error ():
    4:     <title>Pmo</title>
    5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    6:
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    9:   </head>
   10:
(execjs):1

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__652431424_78968160'
```

The application.html.erb file is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syor6.jpg).

The controller was generated in the following way:

```
rails g controller Pages inicio
```

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Nodejs v8.1.2
- Rails v5.1.1
- Ruby v2.3.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial

Answer (score 0):

per your error message, it looks like stylesheet problem (line 7) from your application layout, please check your stylesheets /app/assets/stylesheets/ make user your settings in application.css is correct

Comment: The application.css file contains the following code: `*= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
`

Comment: since you using windows, have you install node.js , if not then you can download and install from https://nodejs.org/en/download/